# Use of “of ” to separate the last name

Tags: names

Sometimes I enconter people with names in which the last part is separated with *of*. I wonder in which cases such usage like *George of Bush*, *John of Doe*, or *Bill of Clinton* is possible.

Comment: In a word, ***ɴᴏ***.

Comment: Those are *locatives,* and say where the people are from. For instance, [*Giordano Bruno*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giordano_Bruno) was called *Iordanus Brunus Nolanus* in Latin, which might be translated *Jordan Brown of Nola*  (he was born in Nola). I would be shocked if these were still used today in English.

Comment: Locative names may still be used in certain cultures - even if the people there are speaking English.  In India, for example, English is a major language, yet locatives can be used even today.  This is usually in addition to full names, (both first and last) - but in some cases they might be used instead of a last name.  They aren't commonly used with English names, as Peter Shor mentioned, but they aren't impossible either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Middle Ages, these were *locative* names, and said where the person was from. For example, [John of Gaunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_of_Gaunt,_1st_Duke_of_Lancaster) was called that because he was born in Ghent. They are not used in English today.